# Refactoring large SQL table with lots of references

Tags: sql-server

We have a database for a case management system that is long overdue some refactoring on a couple of core tables, in order to split them up based on the business area that the columns relate to.

All relations will continue to be 1:1, we just want to avoid having EF models that have to refer to these giant tables, as there's a drive towards being able to deploy certain areas of the system independently of other areas, which is currently unfeasible due to the database structure.

Table 1 has case data and 415 columns, Table 2 has personal data and 564 columns.

Both have upwards of 10 complex triggers, and both are referenced directly by a legacy Delphi front-end, Winform projects & other .NET projects using EF.  Due to this, I have been trying to come up with a solution to allow me to refactor the tables independently of updating all the various front-ends of the system.

I'm about halfway through a plan of:

1. Create view as (SELECT * FROM [Table 1]) (WITH SCHEMABINDING to ensure definition stays the same)
2. Change definition on all existing views referencing the table, to look at new view
3. Rename table to [Table_1_legacy]
4. Rename view from step 1 to [Table 1]
5. Change definition on all existing views to point back at [Table 1] (now a view!)
6. Create INSTEAD OF triggers on new view
7. Refactor [Table_1_legacy]
8. Alter view to be multi-tabled, looking at new refactored tables
9. Alter INSTEAD OF triggers to update/insert to new refactored tables
10. Slowly change all the front-end to remove references to [Table 1] and replace with references to new, smaller refactored tables...

My stumbling block has been the complex triggers already on the original table, which have updates including joins, which are no longer compatible with a view with an INSTEAD OF trigger.  If I disable these, my proof of concept works, and our Delphi and EF both work seamlessly with the new view, as far as I can tell.

My question: Am I going completely up the wrong tree with this or is it worth persevering with re-writing/removing the troublesome existing triggers?

Are there known strategies for refactoring databases when there are so many independent pieces of front-end code referencing the database structure directly? I can't see a way of introducing a data layer to abstract away from the database, without accidentally missing places.

Answer (score -1):

I would not disturb the existing table. Instead create new tables (as desired) and change front-end to point to new tables. And then migrate the data into new tables. This will be smooth process.

Comment: Another issue that I perhaps didn't stress is how core those 2 tables are to the rest of the database structure. There's about 800 SPs/functions referencing one of them, and 130 foreign keys.

We could create the new tables, but I can't see how we'd sync the migration of data across to the new tables, at the same time of migrating the front-end.  It would be considered as close to a total re-write as you could get.